# Raphy Charts - TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, charts, raphael, graphael

I am trying to use [Raphy Charts](http://softwarebyjosh.com/raphy-charts/) but continuously receiving the following error message:"TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'a.style') raphy-chart.min.js:31:452"

This is the code ([on Github](https://github.com/kicsipixel/raphytest)):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='vendor/js/jquery.min.js'></script>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='vendor/js/raphael.min.js'></script>
     <script type='text/javascript' src='vendor/js/raphy-charts.min.js'></script>
     <script>
      var progress1 = new Charts.CircleProgress('progress-1', 'Sales', 80, 
      {
       font_color: "#fff",
       fill_color: "#222",
       label_color: "#333",
       text_shadow: "rgba(0,0,0,.4)",
       stroke_color: "#6a329e"
      });

      progress1.draw()
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id='progress-1' style='width: 300px; height: 100px;'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try: move script to body after div. Could help because it is referencing id progres-1

Comment: Thank you, Anto. That helped as I described below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script is referencing `div` with id `progres-1` before page is loaded. Script has to be moved after `div` element:

```
<div id='progress-1' style='width: 300px; height: 250px;'></div>

<script>
var progress1 = new Charts.CircleProgress('progress-1', 'Sales', 80, 
{
    font_color: "#fff",
    fill_color: "#222",
    label_color: "#333",
    text_shadow: "rgba(0,0,0,.4)",
    stroke_color: "#6a329e"
});

progress1.draw()
</script>
```

Height was set too low so only part of chart was shown. Changed to `250px`

Comment: So simple and I will never ever figure it out. Thank you very much for spending time and answering!